# Convert String Encoding in C Language

Tags: c++, windows, encoding, utf-8, arabic

Basically I need to convert UTF-8 string to windows-1256 and I do it using following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* convert(char* pszStringToConvert)
{
      int len = strlen(pszStringToConvert);  // get string length
      wchar_t* pwsz = new wchar_t[len+1];       // allocate storage for temporary UNICODE string
      MultiByteToWideChar(65001,0, pszStringToConvert, len, pwsz, len);
      WideCharToMultiByte(1256,0, pwsz, len, pszStringToConvert, len, NULL, FALSE);
      return pszStringToConvert;
}


int main()
{
     char* arabic ="السلام";
    char* win = convert(arabic);


    printf("%s\n%",win);

    return 0;
}
```

My source string is

arabic ="السلام"

But unfortunately my result string becomes

win = Ø§Ù„Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your source string isn't UTF-8 encoded. It uses **some** encoding, chosen at the discretion of your tool chain. If you want a UTF-8 encoded string literal, use the appropriate prefix (see [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal)).

Comment: Besides that, you are potentially writing beyond the end of the character array you passed into your function. Likewise, your `pwsz` buffer may not be sufficiently large either. You need to query `MultiByteToWideChar` for the destination buffer size first. And then, you tagged your question [tag:c], but seem to be using `operator new`. Could you please use the correct tag?

Comment: I changed the tag  thanks.

Comment: char* arabic = u8"السلام" I used that but still get different output than input, my output is Ã˜Â§Ã™â€žÃ˜Â³Ã™â€žÃ˜Â§Ã™â€¦

Comment: In that case, change your `operator new` invocation, and use `std::vector<wchar_t>` instead. That'll fix the memory leak (but won't fix your other bugs, like writing beyond the end of the buffer). Also, since you aren't evaluating any return values, you never know, whether your function calls actually work. You may just returning a garbage result based on the uninitialized garbage buffer (`pwsz`).

Comment: I am not good at c++, I searched for along time for conversion solution like one in c# and found one like above so I tried to use it, if you have better solution, please tell me

Comment: string q = "السلام";
       Encoding wind1256 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;  
//byte[] wind1252Bytes = wind1252.GetBytes(q);
//byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(wind1252, utf8, wind1252Bytes);
byte[] utf8Bytes = utf8.GetBytes(q);
byte[] wind1256Bytes  = Encoding.Convert(utf8, wind1256,utf8Bytes);
//string utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
string wind1256String = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetString(wind1256Bytes);
Console.WriteLine(wind1256String);

Comment: the above code is in C# and it works well ,I want to do the same in c or c++ so if you have any suggestion I will be grateful.

Comment: You are failing at a level that is a lot more fundamental than C++. You have an abundant lack of understanding about character encodings. The lack of experience with C or C++ only adds to the confusion. Anyway, you already know how to do this: You need to call `MultiByteToWideChar` followed by `WideCharToMultiByte`. Why you would want that is completely unclear. It's a rare requirement to destroy data (which you are asking to do).

Comment: I use data with utf-8 encoding but I want to change part of it to windows-1256 to be written in files with new encoding

Comment: ... thereby destroying content. Do you understand, that ANSI (code page) encoding cannot represent every Unicode code point (much in contrast to, say, UTF-8)? It is not immediately obvious, why you decide to purposefully destroy data.

Comment: I think I will not destroy data as all the strings I will convert will be in Arabic.

Comment: There are a great number of Unicode code points, that aren't specifically Arabic, but do show up in Arabic text, that may or may have a representation in CP 1256. What is the rationale for choosing a character encoding that's as brittle as codepage encoding?